# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument Getting invalid argument while parsing xml in python

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I have below xml where i am trying extract value which is required

```
xml = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><GetService xmlns="abc.com/Service">
<GetService xmlns:a="abc.com" xmlns:i="www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<a:EnvironmentName>test</a:EnvironmentName><a:HasUpdates>true</a:HasNewUpdates><a:active>false</a:active><a:Time>13:37:22</a:Time><a:ServiceUrisString>&lt;s&gt;&lt;u t="1" n="net://abc.com/" i="net.tcp://abc.com/" /&gt;&lt;u t="2"
" /&gt;&lt;/s&gt;</a:ServiceUrisString></GetService></GetServiceRegistryResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
'
```

What iam looking for is to get the value for 'active' and 'time' from above xml

```
active=false
time=13:37:22
```

Below is the code

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree=ET.parse(xml)
print(tree)
```

But the parsing not working as expected
Below I am getting following error

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:

SO how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 7):

ET.parse() is a function for reading xml from disk

try ET.fromstring(xml)

Comment: Thank you @DevOps1 this getting parsed. what would be the approach to get following value 
~~~
active=false
time=13:37:22
~~~

Comment: You saved my life! I have been trying to figure this out for far too long. Thanks mate! :D

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks