# Bulk autoreplacing string in the KML file

Tags: python, notepad++, kml

I have a set of placemarks, which include quite a wide description included in its balloon within the property. Next each single description (former column header) is bounded in . Because of the shapefile naming restriction to 10 characters only.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15784/bypassing-10-character-limit-of-field-name-in-shapefiles

I have to retype most of these names manually.

Obviously, I use Notepad++, where I can swiftly press Ctrl+F and toggle Replace mode, as you can see below.

[image]

The green bounded strings were already replaced, the red ones still remain.

Basically, if I press "Replace All" then it works fine and quickly. Unfortunately, I have to go one by one. As you can see I have around 20 separate strings to "Replace all". Is there a possibility to do it quicker? Because all the .kml files are similar to each other, this is going to be the same everywhere. I need some tool, which will be able to do auto-replace for these headers cut by 10 characters limit. I think, that maybe Python tools might be helpful.

https://pythonhosted.org/pykml/

But in the tool above there is no information about bulk KML editing.

How can I set something like the "Replace All" tool for all my strings preferably if possible?

**UPDATE:**

I tried the code below:

```
 files = []
 with open("YesNF016.kml") as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    if line[-1] == '\n':
        files.append(line[:-1])
    else:
        files.append(line)

  old_expression = 'ab'
  new_expression = 'it worked'
  for file in files:
  new_file = ""
  with open(file) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        new_file += line.replace(old_expression, new_expression)
 with open(file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_file)
```

The debugger shows:

**[Errno 22] Invalid argument: ''
File "\test.py", line 13, in 
with open(file) as f:**

whereas line 13 is:

```
  with open(file) as f:
```

The solutions here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/b9cljd/oserror_while_using_elementtree_to_parse_simple/

and

[OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument Getting invalid argument while parsing xml in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836021/oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument-getting-invalid-argument-while-parsing-xml)

weren't helpful enough for me.

Comment: You'd be better off using UNIX.  You could do that like so in UNIX shell :

Comment: du -a | grep '\.kml' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sed -i 's/OLD EXPRESSION/NEW EXPRESSION/g' would edit all your kml files in current dir and sub dirs and replace old expressions by new expression

Comment: But it's UNIX nod WINDOWS right?

Comment: Yes.  However you can have WSL in windows 10, ie, unix commands

Comment: what is WSL? Windows...?

Comment: In short you can have a UNIX shell with wsl, ie, run elf binaries

Comment: Instead of an image, post a sample file **and** expected result. As far as I understand, I see a possibility with conditional replace.

Comment: @Toto I wish I could do it, but I have no idea how to "bite" this issue

Comment: Post an extract of the file **and** expected result, not an image. I can't test anything with  an image.

Comment: OK give me a while I will back to you

Answer (score 0):

So you want to replace all occurence of X to Y in bunch of files ?

Pretty easy.
Just create a file_list.txt containing the list of files to edit.

python code:

```
files = []
with open("file_list.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line[-1] == '\n':
            files.append(line[:-1])
        else:
            files.append(line)

old_expression = 'ab'
new_expression = 'it worked'
for file in files:
    new_file = ""
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            new_file += line.replace(old_expression, new_expression)
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(new_file)
```

Comment: I want to replace the occurrence of all strings marked red. I have a bulk of files with exactly the same <simpledata> description and I need to have some tool, which will replace for me automatically. Is your code able to do so?

Comment: My code replaces an expression by a new one in all files specified in file_list

Comment: I tried in the console and it appears to be fine. However as I am newbie in Python, could you advice me how to run it as an application from the desktop?

Comment: Since you're a beginner, don't try to make a desktop app of my script.  It is too complicated.  Get comfortable with python first

Comment: Could you just tell me how to define the file path, considering that I am launching your code from Online python Compiler, which must see the correct path?

Comment: mail me.  Or put your files on github, I'll fork and edit all.  By the way there is no such thing as a python compiler since python is an interpreted language. (actually yes there is since python is a subset of Cython)

Comment: I will test my code on a list of files and tell you whether that works.  You define file path by creating a file_list.txt in the same directory as the script.  Then, inside that file you put all your file with their path. All file path are separated by a newline

Comment: So I fixed my code and tested it. it works

Comment: Hi,

I am getting this error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836021/oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument-getting-invalid-argument-while-parsing-xml

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'